# Animation does not work in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, animation

```css
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity: 1;}
}
@keyframes fadein {
   from {opacity: 0;}
   to {opacity: 1;}
}
@-moz-keyframes fadein {
   from {opacity: 0;}
   to {opacity: 1;}
}
.animated-div {
   -webkit-animation: fadein 4s 1 forwards;
   -moz-animation: fadein 4s 1 forwards;
   animation: fadein 4s 1 forwards;
}
```

```html
<div class="animated-div">hello</div>
```

Keyframes does not work and  item does not fadein on the page, how to be? 
I tried different combinations of prefixes, does not help. In Chrome, Opera working fine.

Comment: There's an `opacity : 0 !important` applied to the element, how will it animate in any browser?

Comment: @Arpit Goyal Its like default `opacity: 0;`. That for element was not visible in start

Comment: @МаксимМолчанов Im on firefox and it works.

Comment: @МаксимМолчанов it should be without !important in that situation

Comment: @ArpitGoyal deleting `opacity: 0!important` really help,but  i dont know how it was animate in Chrome and Opera even with `opacity: 0!important`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting `opacity: 0!important` really help,but i dont know how it was animate in Chrome and Opera even with `opacity: 0!important`. Thanks all.